# Default Activity not found, though default activity is specified in manifest. Issue happening after updating Android Studio to 3.21

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Not expecting Invalidate/Restart, Clean Project, Rebuild project as i already tried these.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: You obviously didn't declare `MainPageActivity` in Manifest.

Comment: Share your Manifest's code

Answer (score 0):

Note: No need to post my manifest here as i cross checked hundred times about MainPageActivity and it is avaialbe :)

After hours of struggle, finally found this was working.
https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Looks like this is known issue.

From google:

**Configuration on demand with Gradle 4.6 and above:** If you're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.x or 3.1.x with Gradle 4.6 and above, you should disable configuration on demand to avoid some unpredictable build errors. (If you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 or higher, you do not need to take any action to disable configuration on demand.)

Disable configuration on demand in your **gradle.properties** file as shown below:

org.gradle.configureondemand=false